# jQuery/CSS Mobile Icon Animation

Tags: jquery, css

I have incorporated a mobile icon into my personal website. http://www.farrfolio.com which can be found under 980px wide.

The only problem is if I click the css animation twice fast the menu is collapsed showing the "x" instead of the "hamburger" icon. As you will notice I am using jQuery to activate the animation. Is there a way to control the animation with jQuery so that it properly shows the right css animation based off of if the menu is open or closed?

Original Codepen here http://codepen.io/rictorres/pen/ycudz

jQuery

```
$("#menu").click(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
$(this).toggleClass("on");
});
```

CSS

```
 #menu {
 background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
 display: block;
 font-size: 36px; /* change this */
 margin: 4em auto;
 padding: 2.5em 2em;
 width: 2em;
 height: auto;
 }

#menu span {
background: #fff;
display: block;
position: relative;
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

#menu span,
#menu span:before,
#menu span:after {
width: 100%;
height: .2em;
-moz-transition:       all 0.4s;
-o-transition:         all 0.4s;
-webkit-transition:    all 0.4s;
transition:            all 0.4s;
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

#menu span:before,
#menu span:after {
background: #fff;
content: " ";
margin-top: -.6em;
position: absolute;
}

#menu span:after {
margin-top: .6em;
}

#menu.on span {
background: transparent;
}

#menu.on span:before {
-moz-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(.5em, .4em);
-ms-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(.5em, .4em);
-o-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(.5em, .4em);
-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(.5em, .4em);
transform: rotate(45deg) translate(.5em, .4em);
}

 #menu.on span:after {
-moz-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(.45em, -.35em);
-ms-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(.45em, -.35em);
-o-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(.45em, -.35em);
-webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(.45em, -.35em);
transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(.45em, -.35em);
}
```

Comment: i took a minute to play around with your icon. i clicked it in the most chaotic order slow and fast, and it did not collapse or misbehave, not even once. worked smooth all the way. i think its time for you to buy a faster computer.

Comment: I might be misunderstood. Here http://www.farrfolio.com under 980px wide you will be presented with a mobile icon. If you click it the mobile menu drops down presenting you with an "x" instead of "3 bars." If you click that icon fast twice it will show an "x" when the menu is closed. It should show "3 bars" when closed or vice versa for "x."

Comment: @jacks3 make an edit on your original question so that readers get what the issue is right away.

Comment: @carlodurso ok edit made.

Comment: You are right, i have tested it on my phone and indeed it happens as you explained. The issue happens because the menu and the icon get out of sync, it should be solved if you toggle both menu and the icon in the same place, rather than separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Banana @carlodurso thank you guys for your help. What ended up working in the end was the code below.

jQuery

```
setInterval ( function(){

if ( jQuery('.x-nav-collapse').hasClass('in') ){
jQuery("#menu").addClass('on');
}
else {
jQuery("#menu").removeClass('on');
}

}, 300 );
```

Answer (score 0):

an easy way out might be the use of the [.dblclick()](http://api.jquery.com/dblclick/) event handler, though it won't make your code perfect :-)

Comment: This defeats the purpose of showing off the animation as most people won't click the button twice.

Comment: in [jQuery click event, ignore double clicks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674255/jquery-click-event-ignore-double-clicks) you may find better solutions.

If you're looking for elegancy than you need to make the menu aware of the button and animate accordingly.

Comment: here we go: [http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/KTNAq/](http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/KTNAq/). 
And related question: [jQuery Toggle function conflicts with Mouseup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8702166/jquery-toggle-function-conflicts-with-mouseup). Hope it helps.